# Jquery Selectors - substitution variables

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a simple question regarding `jQuery` selectors. I'm using the `tablesorter` and I use a selector to filter out a table that has no records.

```
$('#mytable:has(tbody tr)').tablesorter();
```

The problem arises when I have multiple sorted tables on the page.

```
var x = 0;
while(x < 10) {
    $('#myTable + x:has(tbody tr)').tablesorter();
    x+=1;
}
```

This doesn't work because x is not substituted in the selector. I can't for the life of me see what combination of brackets and quotes will fix this.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `'#myTable'+x+':has(tbody tr)'` as selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTable + ' + x + ':has(tbody tr)').tablesorter();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTable' + x + ':has(tbody tr)').tablesorter();
```

The way you had it the `x` was just a normal character in the string. Break out of the string like this, so that you are instead combining a string, the value of x converted to string, and another string.

---

I was too focused on answering the specific problem you're having. The *real* solution to use a class on the talbes instead, like `.SortableTable` and then simply

```
$('.SortableTalbe:has(tbody tr)').tablesorter();
```

, as others have suggested -- doing away with the manual loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel the need to have multiple tables to be sorted on your page. I would recommend adding a "sorting class" to each table.

So you will reduce your tablesorter() to:

```
$('.mySortableTable:has(tbody tr)').tablesorter();
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would suggest giving all those table the same class name, i.e.

```
<table class="mySortable" ... >
```

Then the query could be much simpler:

```
$('.mySortable:has(tbody tr)').tablesorter();
```

I see no need to use increasing Id's. In most cases it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Good idea but not possible in this situation. The tables are generated and there is no class option.